# Social Auth - Linked In OAuth 2 Not working

Tags: java, oauth, linkedin-api, socialauth

When Social Auth 4.6 and LinkedIn OAuth2 Provider, I am getting an error

***State parameter value does not match with expected value.***

I am using the following code to connect first time:

```
SocialAuthConfig config = SocialAuthConfig.getDefault();
config.load();

manager = new SocialAuthManager();
manager.setSocialAuthConfig(config);

String authenticationURL = manager.getAuthenticationUrl("linkedin2", successURL);
```

And this is the code to get the profile:

```
authMap = SocialAuthUtil.getRequestParametersMap(request);
AuthProvider provider = manager.connect(authMap);
profile = provider.getUserProfile();
```

This works for the first time though, but from next time, it throws an error.
Anyone faced any issues similar to this?

Comment: were you able to get profile details from linkedin, if yes can you tell how?

Answer (score 2):

It is resolved and available in latest socialauth-4.8 version

https://sourceforge.net/projects/socialauth/files/latest/download

Answer (score 0):

I have reported this as a problem here:

https://github.com/3pillarlabs/socialauth/issues/38

You can:

1. fix it by moving config and manager objects to the Application scope;
2. by fixing GooglePlusImpl.java as defined in issue comment.